# Expressing a set of 0-1 strings by Extended Formulation

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, linear-programming, boolean-functions, convex-geometry

Extended Formulation of a polytope $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a system of linear constraints which satisfies the following condition:

$x \in P \iff \exists y\in \mathbb{R}^{d} \mbox{ such that } Ax + By \geq d$

A convex set of $n$-points $x_{1},...,x_{n}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ is defined as $\mbox{conv}(\{x_{1},...,x_{n}\})=\{y\in \mathbb{R}^{n}  |y=c_{1}x_{1}+c_{2}x_{2}+\cdots +c_{n}x_{n}, c_{1}+c_{2}+\cdots +c_{n}=1   \}$

## Question:

Is the following statement true ?

Statement:
For every $P\subseteq  \{0,1\}^{n}$, If we construct a system of linear constraints $ Ax + By \geq d,x\in \mathbb{R}^{n},y\in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ such that

$x \in P \iff \exists y\in \mathbb{R}^{d} \mbox{ such that } Ax + By \geq d$

,then the system of linear constraints $ Ax + By \geq d,x\in \mathbb{R}^{n},y\in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ is a extended formulation of $\mbox{conv}  (P)$  ?

I am not sure about expressing a set of boolean strings by linear constraints.

Answer (score 1):

An *extended formulation* (EF) of a polytope $P\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ is a linear system

\begin{equation}
\label{equation:ExtForm}
Ex + Fy  = g, y\geq 0
\end{equation}

in variables $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{d+r}$ where $E,F$ are real
matrices with $d,r$ columns respectively and $g$ is a column vector
such that $x\in P$ if and only if there exists $y$ such that the equation above holds.

Thus the formulation you described in your question seems to be incorrect.
In special the right side of the inequality is expected to be a vector and not
a number.

I believe that the way in which you represent strings as extremal points of a
polytope is somewhat arbitrary. But a sort of canonical way is to represent
a string $x$ over $\{0,1\}^n$ by a vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$  such that
$v_i=x_i$.

However these extremal points are usually meant to represent the solutions to
a given combinatorial problem. For instance, in the cut polytope is the convex hull
the characteristic vectors of all cuts in the complete graph $K_n=(V_n,E_n)$:

\begin{equation}
\label{equation:CutPolytope}
CUT(n) = conv\{ \chi^{\delta(X)\in \mathbb{R}^{E_n}} | X\subseteq V_n\}
\end{equation}

where $\delta(X)$ is the set of edges from $X$ to its complement $\overline{X}$.
Similarly, the *stable set polytope* is the convex hull of the vectors corresponding
to the characteristic functions of all stable sets of $G$.

\begin{equation}
\label{equation:StableSet}
STAB(G) = conv\{\chi^S \in \mathbb{R}^V | S \mbox{ is a stable set of $G$}\}
\end{equation}

The TSP polytope $TSP(n)$ is the convex hull of all vectors corresponding to the characteristic functions of sets of edges representing the tours in $K_n$:

\begin{equation}
\label{equation:TSP}
TSP(n) = conv\{\chi^F \in \mathbb{R}^{E_n} | F\subseteq E_n \mbox{ is a tour of } K_n\}
\end{equation}

The interest on extended formulations stems from the fact that some polytopes,
such as the Permutahedron,which have an exponential number of facets admit extended formulations with a polynomial number of inequalities. However, recently [Fiorini, Massar, Pokutta, Tiwary and De Wolf](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.0837) proved that any extended formulation of any of the three polytopes described above require an exponential number of innequalities.

Comment: Mateus,Thanks!Your answer is "YES, but exponential linear constraints for several NP-solutions are unavoidable", is'nt you ?

Comment: In your formulation $Ex + Fy  = g, y\geq 0$,equality and $y\geq 0$ is contained.Is equality and $y\geq 0$ necessary ?

Comment: The answer to your question is no, since you are writing $Ax + By \geq d$  and the right hand side of the inneq. has nothing to do with the dimension of $y$. The equality and the $\geq 0$ are without loss of generality, since any extended formulation can be put in this form without changing the number of innequalities (See "slack form" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). But this fact is far from being research level. If you want to see explicit formulations of polytopes I would point to http://eprints.lse.ac.uk/31670/

Comment: Sorry....of course, I know the notion of "slack".